# How do I loop through elements to apply a '.active' class when they're visible on screen?

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to create an on scroll effect when the user scrolls down the page and see's elements become active once they reach that point of the page where the element is visible.

On my page I have 5 instances of an element (.highlight) each positioned at different points on a timeline. Currently I have managed to get this to work on one element (And therefore it applies the .active class to all of them at the same time). However, I'm struggling with the syntax to loop it through all elements so that they become '.active' when they're visible.

I don't think i'm far off, here's my js:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var $elem = $('.highlight');
  var $window = $(window);

  var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();
  var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();
  if (elemBottom < docViewBottom) {
    $('.highlight').addClass('active');
  }
});
```

This works out where the element is on the page and then applies the class when it becomes visible but it applies the active class to all of course, I just don't have the js knowledge to work out how to treat each individual element.

Technically, I could just repeat this function and use a different class for each instance, however i'm pretty sure that's bad practice.

Comment: well you are selecting all the elements with the class... you need to loop over all the elements and check. jquery each()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Instead of calculating the position of the element couldn't you just use</strike>

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if($('.highlight').is(':visible')) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

*Not tested but I'm sure .is(':visible') is the way to go.

Ok I see I tested that and it's no good as I think visible is anything that takes up space on the page and not anything that's visible in the viewport.

However using your original code and ibrahim mahrir's reply using the .each function this should work.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $('.highlight').each(function() {
          var $elem = $(this);
          var $window = $(window);
          var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
          var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();
          var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
          var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();
          if (elemBottom < docViewBottom) {
            $elem.addClass('active');
          }
    });
});
```

So for each .highlight assign elem as $(this) then using your original calculation of the element position.

Comment: `$(this)` refer to `window` as it is the element scrolled.

Comment: I'm afraid not. I tried this from a previous question on here but it doesn't seem to work at all. I'm using jquery-1.10.2.js, something to do with that perhaps?

Comment: Also just occured to me that you should wrap this in a function and run it on document.ready and .on scroll so if an element is visible when the page loads it will be active so you don't need to scroll to make it active.

Comment: This will check the Y-Axis only. Not suitable for his needs.

Comment: This worked a treat! Thanks very much. Scrolling is always going to occur to get to these elements so that solution works fine but I appreciate the thought of your answer Paul.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check if the element is contained (visible entirely) not just visible.

```
function isContained(elem){
    var $elem = $(elem);
    var x = $elem.offset().left;
    var y = $elem.offset().top;
    var w = $elem.width();
    var h = $elem.height();

    var $window = $(window);
    var wx = $window.scrollLeft();
    var wy = $window.scrollTop();
    var ww = $window.width();
    var wh = $window.height();

    if(x < wx || x + w > wx + ww) return false;
    if(y < wy || y + h > wy + wh) return false;
    return true;
}

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $('.highlight').each(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        if(isContained($this)) {
            $this.addClass('active');
        }
        // if you want to remove the class active if an element is not visible uncomment this
        /*
        else{
            $this.removeClass('active');
        }
        */
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked, however, same problem, it applied the active class to all at the same time, and when they weren't visible. It applied the class as soon as i scrolled the tiniest bit. 

The ".highlight" elements are absolutely positioned on the page, is this part of the problem?

Comment: @LouisAnderson the `is(':visible')` checks if an element is visible (even the tiniest bit).

Comment: I understand that, however the element was NOT visible and the class was applied in inspect element the second i scrolled. The class was applied to all elements. Some of which were far down the page and no where near what was currently visible :-/

Comment: @LouisAnderson this (the new answer) works when the whole element is visible. Plus you don't remove the class `.active` when the element is not visible that's why you end up with elements not visible but having the `.active` class. (Unccomment the `else` statement if you want to remove it when the element is no longer visible).

Comment: Ibrahim, thanks a lot I will try this also. The other solution seems more lightweight, but it looks like this has more functionality, what with removing the .active class as well.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a good article to keep in mind when dealing with onscroll events. The problem is that onscroll fires off the assigned event waaay too many times if it's not managed. If you got a loop in your event or multiple methods are fired off, especially if you are making changes in the DOM, those will get fired off for each onscroll event. Keep in mind to minimize the amount of times the onscroll event fires, like suggested in the following article: http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/